# Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition Location service is very slow

Tags: ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4

I'm new to AskUbuntu so apologies if I'm going about this the wrong way. I got a mate to ship a Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition to me in Australia recently. Loving it for the most part, but the location service is very very slow to find where I am. I turn on location service, GPS, data service and wifi but it just seems to take inexcusably long (often more than ten minutes, sometimes it just doesn't seem to be able to find me at all).

Anyone else had similar issues or have any idea why this might be happening?